# SSIS read/write to variable in script task

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, ssis, dts

I have a variable called **Valint** that i need to read/write to in a script task, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public class scriptmain
inherits usercomponent

dim counter as integer
dim Valint as integer
.....


Public sub new()
counter = 0
end sub

public overrides sub input0_processintputrow(byval row as input0buffer)
Dim vars as IDTSvariables100 = nothing

Me.variableDispenser.lockforread("User::Valint")
Me.variableDispenser.GetVariables(vars)

counter = CType (vars("User:: Valint").Value, integer)
vars.Unlock()

counter +=1

Me.VariableDispenser.LockoneForWrite("User::Valint", vars)
vars("User::Valint").Value = counter
vars.Unlock()
End Sub
```

For some reason my output is always 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in a data flow task, yes? You can't modify a variable in the script transformation, at least during the processinputrow subroutine.

Fortunately, it seems like the type of modification you are doing can be done-just in different subroutines.

My SSIS Scripting Beta book by Donald Farmer is a thousand miles from me so please forgive the imprecision of this code. The important thing is that you can only write to the user variable from the PostExecute event.

```
public class scriptmain
inherits usercomponent

dim counter as integer
dim Valint as integer
.....


Public sub new()
counter = 0
end sub

public overrides sub input0_processintputrow(byval row as input0buffer)
    counter +=1
End Sub

Public overrides sub PostExecute()
    Dim vars as IDTSvariables100 = nothing

    Me.variableDispenser.lockforread("User::Valint")
    Me.variableDispenser.GetVariables(vars)

    counter = CType (vars("User:: Valint").Value, integer)
    vars.Unlock()
    Me.VariableDispenser.LockoneForWrite("User::Valint", vars)
    vars("User::Valint").Value = counter
    vars.Unlock()
End Sub
```